# Python fast indexing: Get slices of a 2D matrix using a 2D index array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, profiling

By profiling line by line my code, I observed that the bottleneck of my program, is the following command:

```
A[index_array]
```

Where **A** and **index_array** are  2D matrices. The result is a 3D array. Right now uses the 40% of the time in a program that uses also costly commands like np.einsum and the Softmax function.

I'm new in python coding and i can't find a more efficient and faster way to write that. Could someone give an advice?